# Change query to allow one type of column value per row

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

[image]

I am trying to remove the third row from the results table above.
The query which returns the data including the third row (exactly the table of results above) is this:

```
SELECT service.code, line, service.region
FROM service
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.service = service.code
```

The above query needs to be changed to say: "Select lines with a region of *either* EM or Y region, you can't have a line with two `region`s, you can only have a `line` with one `region` (don't need to be able to choose preference over EM or Y (there are also several more regions)).

As stated above, the query should then leave these results:

[image]

PS: Sorry for the poor title, having a tough time trying to come up with a simple way to describe what I'm asking above, edits welcome.

Comment: My bad didnt see column called line,just leave the query as it really is.

Comment: @Mihai I have simplified it slightly as it was unnecessarily over complicated. The query still returns the same results. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT service.code, line, MAX(service.region) AS region
FROM service
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.service = service.code
WHERE region IN ('Y', 'EM')
GROUP BY service.code, line
HAVING SUM(region IN ('Y', 'EM')) = 1;
```

The `HAVING` clause "counts" the rows per group and filters those where multiple regions were found.

The aggregate function on region in the `SELECT` clause is just to fullfil the rule "either you have the same column in the group by clause or apply an aggregate function". Although MySQL allows this, I'm no big fan of it, as it leads to a random row out of the group. You can use `MIN()` too, doesn't make a difference here.

(Answering the comment:) An alternative would be

```
...
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT region) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to change the query to do the same thing without having to specifically state which region (eg not having to say Y, or EM)?

Comment: Yes, added it to my answer.